# Teradata SQL- Split a string and search for that combination in respective fields

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a set of fixed length strings in excel. How to split the string and provide the condition in `WHERE` clause? I mean

eg: P0025583740005, P0025583740002, P0068377440009, P0067264370006....
the last four digits are the PIN number and the rest is the Claim number. 
Claim Number - P002558374; PIN - 0005

while I'm searching for these in `teradata` sql, I'm manually splitting the values like

```
SELECT * from myTable 
where (Claim_nbr = 'P002558374' and PIN='0005') 
OR (Claim_nbr = 'P002558374' and PIN='0002')
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from myTable 
WHERE Claim_nbr || PIN IN ('P0025583740005', 'P0025583740002', ...)
```

Comment: I tried the concat, it gives me Claim_NBR doesn not match the defined type name

Comment: What type are Claim_NBR and PIN of?

Comment: data type used is varchar(30) for both

Comment: `CONCAT` is not valid Standard SQL, which uses `Claim_nbr || PIN` instead.